# Downloads page menu live update HTML and Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a menu page where you have 3 tabs: Windows, Linux, Mac. Then when you hit Windows it not only downloads the windows installer but also opens install instructions for Windows. If you open the Linux tab, it will download the Debian package but also open Linux instructions on how to install it. I want it kind of like this site. Also, try making it simple because I am only a beginner in HTML.

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows

Example:

When I click on the Linux tab on this page:

[Click HERE for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DiLd.png)

the instructions popup reads instructions for the Linux install:

[Click HERE for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmXJc.png)

But when I got to the Windows tab, the instructions tab changes:

[Click HERE for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6u9b.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add event listeners to all the three tabs, like if the user clicks windows then on click change the link of the download button to the target file you wish to download and similarly for the other two.

If the download button is:

`<button href="/path/to/windowsDownload" download>Download</button>`

Now if the user clicks, Linux button, add event listener to Linux button as:

```js
document.getElementById('linux-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
       document.getElementsByTagName('button'[0].setAttribute('href', '/path/to/LinuxDownload')
})
```

Similarily add an event listener for the other two buttons as well, i.e windows and mac respectively.

Comment: That is for the download itself but what about changing the text of the instructions. For example:

Look at the question where I posted a picture of what I am talking about.

Also, Thanks so far!

Comment: For this you can use local storage or session storage, as soon as any of the three button is clicked save the name of the preferred choice in the storage and then on click of download button check for the local storage or session storage stored value and accordingly change the inner.HTML or inner.text of the instructions popup and display up the popup